# File contents incorrectly indicating a value is already there

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

I'm currently using the following code:

```
private void NewContactSaveButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NewContactTextBoxName.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Contact Name");
    }
    else
    {   
        ContactInformation.ContactName = NewContactTextBoxName.Text;
        string contactpath2 = @"CurrentContacts.txt";
        string contactpath3 = @"" + ContactInformation.ContactName + ".txt";
        string Readfile = File.ReadAllText(contactpath2);
        if (Readfile.Contains(ContactInformation.ContactName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This contact already exsists. Please rename the contact you're trying to create or delete the exsisting contact");
        }
        else
        {
            //save contact to file
        }
    }
}
```

And the following class file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Contact_List
{
    public class ContactInformation
    {
        public static string ContactName;
        public static string ContactCellNumber;
        public static string ContactOtherNumber;
        public static string ContactRelationship;
        public static string ContactEmail;
        public static string ContactNote;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the following line of code:

```
MessageBox.Show("This contact already exists. Please rename the contact you're trying to create or delete the existing contact");
```

*always* runs when click the Save Button.  I don't understand why and would like it to ONLY run when it's true.

Comment: Your file content **surely contains** this `ContactInformation.ContactName`, what's that value?

Comment: @KingKing the value of `ContactInformation.ContactName` is empty but now I see that I have to set it to `NewContactTextBoxName.Text`. I think.

Comment: @Shaquanda looks like your file content always contains this `.txt`, try initializing some value for `ContextInformation.ContactName` to test it.

Comment: @KingKing I'm kind of new to all this and don't quite understand what it is that you're saying, sadly :( Could you give me an example of what you mean or explain it in different words?

Comment: @Shaquanda **YOU HAVE TO Assign** your `ContactName` to some value other than the `empty string`.

Comment: @KingKing I added `ContactInformation.ContactName = NewContactTextBoxName.Text;` to it and set all of the `ContactInformation` strings = to nothing and I get the error "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: @Shaquanda Make sure you don't have the file open in a text editor (most likely cause). File.ReadAllText closes itself after doing it's job so unless you are opening the same file someone else in your code and not disposing of it (if it doesn't auto close), it is most definitely opened elsewhere.